# Unable to cast object of type 'RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'ListBoxItem'

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, casting, listbox

I have this strange problem where I am unable to get an item from a ListBox. I have even tried to use the code from [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) but it fails in my situation with a message: *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.* The ListBox is binded to colors from XAML.

```xaml
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
<Window.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
                    Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
        </sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"
                    MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
</ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<!-- etc -->

<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxColor"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         Margin="5" Grid.RowSpan="5" SelectedIndex="113">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Stroke="Black" Margin="2"
                           StrokeThickness="1" Height="20" Width="50"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```vb
Private Sub ListBoxColor_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, _
            e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListBoxColor.SelectionChanged
        Dim lbsender As ListBox
        Dim li As ListBoxItem

        lbsender = CType(sender, ListBox)
        li = CType(lbsender.SelectedItem, ListBoxItem)
```

It breaks on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in your list box are of type `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`.  So you need to do something like this:

C#

```
if (ListBoxColor.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var selectedItem = (PropertyInfo)ListBoxColor.SelectedItem;
    var color = (Color)selectedItem.GetValue(null, null);
    Debug.WriteLine(color.ToString());
}
```

VB.NET

```
If ListBoxColor.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim selectedItem As PropertyInfo = _
        DirectCast(ListBoxColor.SelectedItem, PropertyInfo)
    Dim color As Color = DirectCast(selectedItem.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing), Color)
    Debug.WriteLine(color.ToString())
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The items in your `ListBox` are properties of the `Colors` class. You can't cast a property to a `ListBoxItem` because it isn't one.

Try calling `ListBox.ContainerFromElement(lbsender.SelectedItem)` instead.

MSDN Source: [ContainerFromElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346420.aspx)